# Diagonal Gradient in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer, gradient

I want to use a diagonal gradient in my background.

I have read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532887%28VS.85%29.aspx), and I found that it has just only horizontal gradient and vertical gradient in IE.

Is it possible to make the gradient in IE show in the diagonal like Firefox?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using CSS, but it's kind of a hacked together solution involving two layers. You can read about the details of it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6093708/diagonal-gradient-in-ie/7233764#7233764).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to use a `background-image` though so there may be a limited element size depending on how much you want a page to cost, and you will need to use a separate image.

HTML5 brings along [SVG images](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics) though which are scalable and take up little space.

Comment: Thank you. But does it possible not to use background-image?

Comment: No, in fact the javascript gradient you linked to isn't valid javascript, and will only work on later versions of IE as opposed to the majority of browsers, which follow the rules.

There may be a CSS3 gradient property but almost nothing supports CSS3 at the moment.