# HTML/CSS Design for the Background

Tags: html, css, image, background

I need a help regarding the background of the website, below are the details I want to know:

- Different gradient background on left and right of the website (It should work also on all the IE Browser).
- How will I do that using the HTML/CSS?

Please help. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: have you tried something?

Comment: So you want a solution that will work on IE 1.0+.  Good luck with that.

Comment: I used this before for the background, but there's a problem always:

html {background:url(../images/bg-right.png) top right repeat-y;}
body{font-family:Arial; font-size:12px; background:url(../images/bg-left.png) top left repeat-y;}

Comment: IE only worth to download firefox, chrome, etc... This is problem in IE.

Comment: @AntonioM.Mérida — Most people have to build websites for the public at large, not just for themselves. Our opinions about the quality of browsers don't really matter.

Comment: @Shankar what do you mean not a client for stackoverflow?

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to work on older browsers, you could write something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/ftcjZ/2/

This is more complicated html - it all depands on what exact browser do you need to run this on.

CSS:

```
.bg-left { background: url('http://cdn.imghack.se/images/3be5ae39376f069c0f49dd0cf09e74c7.png') top left no-repeat; } 
.bg-right { padding: 0 118px 0 125px; background: url('http://cdn.imghack.se/images/ae53c28777043687b9a110e867798cb5.png') top right no-repeat; }
.main-content { height: 800px; background-color: white; }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="bg-left">
  <div class="bg-right">
    <div class="main-content">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: I updated the code changing margin for main container to padding in `.bg-right` as this is more reliable solution.

Comment: not supported in Safari.

Comment: Hi Lucas, this is a good idea but I think this will not work well if you tried minimize the browser :)

Answer (score 0):

One best idea to work in all the browsers and most of the resolutions is, using a huge image, with a separation in the middle, having a width of `2048` and make the vertical scrolling fixed.

This would work in all the browsers.

```
body {background: url("huge-image.png") center top no-repeat;}
```

**To all who say bg will be big.**

An image of resolution: `19488 x 3552` and the size is just `51 KB`. Check it out:

[image]
<sub>(source: [znate.ru](http://lib.znate.ru/pars_docs/refs/35/34496/34496_html_m46d9bb81.gif))</sub>

Comment: huge-image = huge bandwidth = slow = potentially expensive (for site and visitors)

Comment: @Quentin Huge Image + This case = small size = low bandwidth = more visitors!!!

Comment: You could just have two separate images, one for the left div and one for the right div.  You could have a single slice (i.e. 1000px x 1) and add a `repeat: repeat-x` for the length of the div.

Comment: **To all who say bg will be big.** An image of resolution: `19488 x 3552` and the size is just `51 KB`. Check it out: http://lib.znate.ru/pars_docs/refs/35/34496/34496_html_m46d9bb81.gif

Comment: @BLaZuRE That doesn't work.

Comment: @PraveenKumar — That's a solid black image. Solid black images compress really well!

Comment: @PraveenKumar Why wouldn't it work?

Comment: @Quentin Optimization is the key! :)

Comment: Good idea, but the gradient doesn't adjust to the page length.

Answer (score 0):

1. Generate your body background [here](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)
2. Create centered container div with and transparent curtain image background
3. Create centered website-container div in container div 100% height and set the background to the grey color

Good luck.

**Clarification for Quentin's comments**: use diagonal gradient:

```
background: #b5bdc8; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #b5bdc8 0%, #828c95 36%, #28343b 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(0%,#b5bdc8), color-stop(36%,#828c95), color-stop(100%,#28343b)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #b5bdc8 0%,#828c95 36%,#28343b 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #b5bdc8 0%,#828c95 36%,#28343b 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #b5bdc8 0%,#828c95 36%,#28343b 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(135deg,  #b5bdc8 0%,#828c95 36%,#28343b 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#b5bdc8', endColorstr='#28343b',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
```

Comment: You're recommending the same tool as Abdul Malik; I still don't see any options there to create the pair of side by side gradients.

Comment: Hello Jan, this is not working in IE7

Comment: @Quentin I suggest **body** background. The "side-by-side" effect is mentioned to place the website-container div in step 3

Comment: @JanTuroň — No, step three is the grey backgound middle section. Not the white to black gradient on the left or the grey to black gradient on the right.

Comment: @JNGarcia87 IE7 is almost dead browser today: http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_explorer.asp If someone still uses it, he is not surprised with missing background gradient.

Comment: W3Schools' browser stats are among the least representative of all the sources of browser stats out there. Their sample is terribly biased.

Comment: @Quentin I updated the answer to clarify the gradient.

Comment: @JanTuroň Yes, but the problem is, our client requires to work on that design.

Comment: @JNGarcia87 Then use [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) for IE7 fallback or ask the customer if he wants better performance for 98% people traded for minor background change for the 2%.

Answer (score 0):

this is method by which you can make background texture through CSS

```
background: linear-gradient(left, white 50%, #8b0 50%);
background-size: 100px 100px;
```

note:you can change the value of polarity and linearity and then define different background throughout the page through background-position

Also check this out.-->http://lea.verou.me/css3patterns/

> Its also possible to use image as a gradient base. open this [noisetexturegenerator.com](http://noisetexturegenerator.com) and try below thing

```
 body { background-image:url('gradient image'); background-repeat:repeat-x; }
```

Comment: Is it possible to use image of gradient repeated instead use css3?

Comment: Yes it is absolutely possible. See My edit in last 3 lines/.

Answer (score -1):

You can use css-gradient. This should work with all browsers.

```
background-image: linear-gradient(left top, rgb(232,232,232) 16%, rgb(122,122,122) 58%, rgb(115,115,115) 79%);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left top, rgb(232,232,232) 16%, rgb(122,122,122) 58%, rgb(115,115,115) 79%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left top, rgb(232,232,232) 16%, rgb(122,122,122) 58%, rgb(115,115,115) 79%);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left top, rgb(232,232,232) 16%, rgb(122,122,122) 58%, rgb(115,115,115) 79%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left top, rgb(232,232,232) 16%, rgb(122,122,122) 58%, rgb(115,115,115) 79%);

background-image: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    left top,
    right bottom,
    color-stop(0.16, rgb(232,232,232)),
    color-stop(0.58, rgb(122,122,122)),
    color-stop(0.79, rgb(115,115,115))
);
```

Older versions of IE don't support gradient, so you have to make second div container, which will be transparent on other browsers.

And define new css for older versions of IE, e.g.:

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]> 
<style>

    .diaggradientback
    {
        position:absolute;
        left:0;
        top:0;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        overflow:hidden;
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType='1', startColorstr='#ffa885', endColorstr='#330000');
    }

    .diaggradientfront
    {
        position:absolute;
        left:0;
        top:0;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        overflow:hidden;
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType='0', startColorstr='#bbffa885', endColorstr='#bb330000');
    }
</style> 
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Shouldn't the standard CSS come after the vendor prefix CSS so it will win at the cascade?

Comment: This gives a horizontal gradient. The question is asking for *two* vertical gradients next to each other.

Comment: Is that will work on IE7?

Comment: you get a gradient from top left to bottom right.

Comment: For IE 6-8 you need two div containers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6093708/diagonal-gradient-in-ie

Comment: Not working in IE7, the reason I'm pushing through IE is because our target market is using IE.

Comment: You should use if-Comments for IE and define separate css for IE6-8. 
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<style>...</style>
<![endif]-->